# iOS 9 and 10: blank space added at the screen top while using safe area layout guide

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide

In my `swift 4` project I have `iOS 9.0` as `deployement target` and I'm using the `safe area layout guide`.

In the `storyboard`, I always give 0 as value between my main `view` top space and the `safe area` top. When I run the application in `iOS 9` or `iOS 10` I'm having a white space at the top.

How can I remove this white space without disabling the `safe area layout guide`?

Comment: Are you using navigationController?

Comment: @MeenorRanpura yes but I hide the navigationBar. Also all is working fine in iOS 11, I'm getting problems with iOS 9 and 10

Answer (score 3):

Goto `Storyboard` > `Select the ViewController` > `Attribute Inspector` (3rd Tab from right in the right pane.) > Uncheck `Adjust Scroll View insets`.

Comment: can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are testing on iPhone X? You can change safe area insets such way:

```
   var newSafeArea = UIEdgeInsets()
   newSafeArea.top -= 20
   self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea
```

Comment: I test in iOS 6 for the iOS 9

Comment: I got this error 'additionalSafeAreaInsets' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer'

Comment: Yes, make sense. Missed that you are testing in below iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but in the storyboard views don't calculate the navigationbar height and therefor you will have an (often 44px) white space. You can remove this by either as Lazy said, by turning of `Adjust Scroll View insets` or you can do it programmatically by setting `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` in your `viewDidLoad()`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout tells you some more about it.